# Ruby open file on another server/network share

Tags: ruby, ssh

Right now I'm using

`open("/home/some/file.txt", "a") { |f| f << sometxtdata}`

What I want to do is connect to the same file on another server like:

`open("user@someaddress:/home/some/file.txt", "a") {|f| f << sometxtdata}`

I've tried the Net::SSH.start which connects, but I can't figure out how to reference the file as a local one. Any help/thoughts would be appreciated. Let met know if I didn't describe the question well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is a procedural problem, rather than a programming one?

If the file on both systems is the same, then I assume you want to open it on the other system to sync its contents. If that is true, then it might make more sense to use `scp` or `rsync` to copy the local version of the file to the other host and overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

You could mount the remote location using [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). It would then appear as if it was local.